# Irreducible Polynomials and Ring Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

[image]

Help and hints for parts (c) and (d) ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For $c$: Which elements of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ are squares?

For $d$: Remember that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^2-3\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}_7[\sqrt{3}]$. Can you find homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{Z}_7[x] \to\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^2-3\rangle$?